# Count number of cells in HTML table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to count the number of table cells of a particular row having a background color, or the number of cells in a row of a table having no color using JavaScript only.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet for this? Share minimal code or working example, so we can understand the question and help you.

Comment: Select a row and count all the colored cells using a specific classname.

Comment: What you are looking for is [window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). If you run into any troubles implementing that, just ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example on how you can iterate through cells for a specific row:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var _cells = table.rows[0].cells;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = _cells.length

var greenCells = 0;

for (cell = 0; cell < _cells.length; cell++){
 if(_cells[cell].classList.contains('green'))
  greenCells++;
}

console.log('green cells: ', greenCells);
```

```css
#table{
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.green{
background: green;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="green"> row 1</td>
    <td> row 1 </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> row 2 </td>
    <td> row 2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>

Total cells
<span id="result"></span>
```